# How to extract clipboard contents with xsel after clicking on element with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, subprocess, clipboarddata

The following code uses [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) and [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) and  is expected to extract clipboard contents after driver copied to clipboard some content from a webpage:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import subprocess


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def run(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get('some_uri')
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
        link_elem = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i[data-original-title='Copy to clipboard']")))
        link_elem.click()
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i[data-original-title='Copied']")))        
        link = subprocess.check_output(["xsel"])
        print(link)
```

Clipboard contents are printed, but it's not the one which was copied by the python code, but some clipboard contents from the past. How to extract clipboard contents, correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
link = subprocess.check_output(["xsel", "--clipboard"])
```

instead of

```
link = subprocess.check_output(["xsel"])
```

From [xsel man](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/xsel.1x.html):

> -b, --clipboard operate on the CLIPBOARD selection.

By default *xsel* echoes *PRIMARY selection* and i needed *CLIPBOARD selection*.
More about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139191/whats-the-difference-between-primary-selection-and-clipboard-buffer).